# Can people with disability use computers to pray in their locality?

Tags: salat

I have an idea of developing a social network where people who can't go to the mosque for a valid reason can use a computer to virtually pray together in their locality. Is is right in Islam to do so? My users are people with disabilities.

Comment: I think a congregation is only valid if one is not separated from the imam and can at least hear or see him. This means one should be in the same location. For example even if you could hear the imam due to speakers in your appartement which might be next to the mosque you couldn't follow his prayer at home as it wouldn't be a valid congregation. So i'm afraid this is a nice idea but they couldn't pray together.

Comment: Its possible to transfer Imam voice as audio to user but takes more efforts. Its good idea but my suggestion is check till you get perfect answer then implement

Comment: @Medi1Saif:  Interesting, yet concerning.  In the mosques I've been to in China, women pray in another room, in which the imam is broadcast via speaker.

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones the major point is are you praying in a congregation, this means together in one location, if you are praying in distinct locations that is no more a congregation. And you seem to pray in the women room, some mosques also have a screen in the women's room, so that they can see the imam.

Comment: Also. do people have to be behind the imam to pray? Because when distributed via internet, people will be both behind in front of the imam.